# Request Aborted | Остановка ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Сервер - node.js
Отправляю файл на сервер с ajax запросом, прогресс загрузки отображается. Есть кнопка, которая останавливает этот ajax запрос (xhr.abort()). После этого сервер падает с ошибкой request aborted. Что делать?

```js
app.post("/blog/add", function (req, res, next) {
        //Проанализируем загрузку файла
        var form = new multiparty.Form();
        var wayImage = "/files/";

        form.on('part', function (part) {
            var path = './public/files/' + part.filename;
            wayImage += part.filename;
            var out = fs.createWriteStream(path);
            part.pipe(out);
        });

        form.on('close', function () {
            //Отправка ссылки на картинку
            res.send(wayImage);
        });

        form.on('error', function () {
            console.log('error');
        });

        form.parse(req);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер скорее всего падает, так как у веб-сервера (который является `EventEmitter`'ом, т.е. генератором событий) нет обработчика события `error`

```
.on('error',function(){ /* ... */ })
```

который срабатывает, когда возникает любая ошибка запроса (соединение отвалилось, пользователь/браузер прервал запрос и т.п.)

Когда нет обработчика `error`, `EventEmitter` видя необработанное событие `error`, бросает исключение, которое и останавливает сервер.

---

### Апдейт

> Оно есть у меня. добавил код выше

С кодом стало понятней.

Как говорит документация **multiparty** https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty#events

> Note that an 'error' event will be emitted both from the form and from the current part.

т.е. part тоже кинет ошибку, поэтому перед `part.pipe(out);` надо добавить

```
part.on('error', function () {
    console.log('part error');
    // ну и закрыть out, удалить файл
});
```

Comment: Оно есть у меня. добавил код выше

Comment: @Dindro добавил в ответ.